# Batch file to run Python scripts doesn't work if I import pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, batch-file

I'm trying to execute a python script with pandas module from a batch file and it doesn't work. To check the problem I ran a script with and without importing pandas, the first version is working, the second one not. I use the same batch file to run the script:

```
@echo off

"C:\Users\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\pythonw.exe" "C:\Users\.spyder-py3\csv.py"
```

When I run the second scripts a cmd window opens and immediately closes and no .csv file is created.
Thanks,

This script works:

```
import tkinter as tk   

root= tk.Tk()    
canvas1 = tk.Canvas(root, width = 350, height = 250) 
canvas1.pack()

button1 = tk.Button (root, text='Exit Application', command=root.destroy) 
canvas1.create_window(170, 130, window=button1) 

root.mainloop()
```

This one does not work:

```
import tkinter as tk   
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['John', 'Peter'],
                   'color': ['red', 'purple'],
                   'city': ['NY', 'LA']})
path = 'C:\\Users\\Documents\\Python\\data\\save.csv'
df.to_csv(path)

root= tk.Tk()    
canvas1 = tk.Canvas(root, width = 350, height = 250) 
canvas1.pack()

button1 = tk.Button (root, text='Exit Application', command=root.destroy) 
canvas1.create_window(170, 130, window=button1) 

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: And what have you done to try and debug your python code?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by _"Does not work"_? That is an extemely broad, and ultimatelty a bad description of a problem. Are there errors? Does it not do something you want it to etc? please edit your question and clarify.

Comment: @Gerhard: I'm not experienced programmer but I try to be more precise. I would expect the code to open a window with a button which I can press to close the window itself and I expect it to save .csv file. On the contrary, it does none of these: no button appears and no .csv file is saved. I do not get any error message, I only see a cmd window opening and closing immediately after.

Comment: put a pause at the bottom of your batch script, the python script will throw an error, you can catch it in that window.

Comment: @Gerhard: I put the pause but I get no error message in the cmd window. I made many attempts and it looks like it depends on the package import: some packages (like pandas or numpy) prevent the script from working. I double checked and all packages are save in same directory.

Comment: Hi, I made further attempts: if I run the command lines on Anaconda prompt, it works fine but when I launch the .bat file it runs in CMD prompt. So I set path variable for python dir and I can run python.exe from CMD and use standard command; but when I try to import pandas from CMD I get error: "Missing required dependencies {0}".format(missing_dependencies))
ImportError: Missing required dependencies ['numpy']. If I try to import numpy I get: ImportError:
Importing the multiarray numpy extension module failed.